# How to properly clean-up a QWidget / manage a set of windows?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget, window-management

Let's say I have 2 windows in my application, and two classes responsible for them:
`class MainWindow: public QMainWindow` and `class SomeDialog: public QWidget`.

In my Main Window I have a button. When it is clicked, I need to display the second window. I do it this way:

```
SomeDialog * dlg = new SomeDialog();
dlg.show();
```

Now, the user does something in the window, and closes it. At this point I want to get some data from that window, and then, I suppose, I will have to `delete dlg`. But how do I catch the event of that window being closed?

Or is there another way not to have a memory leak? Maybe It would be better to create an instance of each window on startup, and then just `Show()`/`Hide()` them?

How do I manage such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose window flag: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(parent);
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)
// set content, do whatever...
dialog->open();
// safely forget about it, it will be destroyed either when parent is gone or when the user closes it.
```

Comment: The ctor takes window flags, not widget attributes. The correct call is dialog->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose )

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld thanks. I couldn't compile when I typed that up so I never checked.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Closing the dialog means? Say I have a button and call the slot close(), what happens then? Will the dialog be cleared from memory?

Comment: and what happens if I use deletelater() instead of close()?

Answer (score 3):

It is advised to use `show()` / `exec()` and `hide()` instead of dynamically creating the dialog every time you want to show it. Also use `QDialog` instead of `QWidget`.

In the constructor of your main window create it and hide it

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
     // myDialog is class member. No need to delete it in the destructor
     // since Qt will handle its deletion when its parent (MainWindow)
     // gets destroyed. 
     myDialog = new SomeDialog(this);
     myDialog->hide();
     // connect the accepted signal with a slot that will update values in main window
     // when the user presses the Ok button of the dialog
     connect (myDialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(myDialogAccepted()));

     // remaining constructor code
}
```

In the slot connected to the buttons's `clicked()` event simply show it, and if necessary pass some data to the dialog

```
void myClickedSlot()
{
    myDialog->setData(data);
    myDialog->show();
}

void myDialogAccepted()
{
    // Get values from the dialog when it closes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subclass from `QWidget` and reimplement

`virtual void QWidget::closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * event )`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent

Also it looks like the widget you want to show is a dialog. So consider using `QDialog` or it's subclasses. `QDialog` has useful signals you can connect to:

```
void    accepted ()
void    finished ( int result )
void    rejected ()
```